# Getting Mouse Coordinates in Gloss(Haskell)

Tags: haskell, mouse, coordinates

I am trying to implement drag-and-drop functionality into a haskell gloss (scheduling) program of mine, but to do that I need to be able to read the coordinates of the mouse. I have been researching how to do this for multiple hours and am coming up empty, except for the fact that it is possible in GLUT, which gloss is based off of, but going that deep is over my head.

I was wondering if there is already some way to do this in gloss, and if not, what library should I switch to?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your serve function you'll want to handle an event such as:

```
serveWorld (EventKey (MouseButton LeftButton) Down xPos yPos) world = ...
```

Or perhaps you don't want to look for buttons but instead just motion?  In that case `serveWorld` should handle `EventMotion`.

You might want to look at the `gloss-draw` example program, which is in the gloss-examples package.

Comment: With "serve function" you mean event handler, correct? If so, are you saying that the (float,float) in the last part of Event is the position of the key? I didn't know what it was, so I have been testing other features with it as "_". Thank you for your quick answer!

Edit: It works, I feel so foolish now for forgetting about it

Comment: No problem!  Yes, the Gloss haddock could be much more specific.  If it were on github...